# understanding linux last reboot command result

Tags: linux, shell

When I ran the last reboot command on linux I receive the following result

> reboot   system boot  2.6.32-38-server Thu Jun  7 10:54 - 15:22  (04:27)

I need to know what the time 04:27 mean?
did the reboot took 4 hours 27 minutes or what?

I tried searching for a description to the last command result but with no luck.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try [`man last`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/last/)?

Comment: He surely did, but on Linux, the man page explains only the first time value of the pseudo user `reboot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `-F` flag, it becomes clear that it is showing system uptime across the interval shown. This is analogous to the use of `last username` which shows how long a login session lasted. Since `reboot` is a pseudo-user in the wtmp file, this is a reasonable way to parallel the output for real users.

Comment: But how is it possible that on my system there are entries: `Tue Oct  2 11:38 - 13:31 (1+01:53)` and 
`Mon Oct  1 11:30 - 13:31 (2+02:01)` - it looks like in both cases the time is counted up to now. Does a crash (power failure) mess things maybe? If there were no such inconsistencies, I would also be sure that the presented time is a system uptime. But in case of not-clean shutdown you cannot trust that value.

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference in time between 10:54 and 15:22, roughly.